# Migrate eclipse project to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to migrate eclipse project to android studio but I couldn't run.I am getting tons of error.

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
```

...

How can I resolve ? My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Button" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display4" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Large" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Subtitle" parent="@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title" parent="@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Small" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Title" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Small" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Switch" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Button" />

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"></style>

    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title"></style>

    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat" />

    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" parent="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" />

    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" parent="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />

    <style name="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material"></style>

    <style name="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>

        <!-- Used by MediaRouter -->
        <item name="isLightTheme">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>

        <!-- Used by MediaRouter -->
        <item name="isLightTheme">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_light</item>

        <!-- Used by MediaRouter -->
        <item name="isLightTheme">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat">

        <!-- Action Bar styling attributes -->
        <item name="actionBarSize">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
        <item name="actionBarDivider">?android:attr/actionBarDivider</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">?android:attr/actionButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">?android:attr/actionMenuTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">?android:attr/actionModeBackground</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">?android:attr/actionModeCloseDrawable</item>
        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">?android:attr/actionModeShareDrawable</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">?android:attr/actionOverflowButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">?android:attr/homeAsUpIndicator</item>

        <!-- For PopupMenu -->
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu</item>

        <!-- General view attributes -->
        <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
        <item name="dividerHorizontal">?android:attr/dividerHorizontal</item>
        <item name="dividerVertical">?android:attr/dividerVertical</item>
        <item name="editTextBackground">?android:attr/editTextBackground</item>
        <item name="editTextColor">?android:attr/editTextColor</item>
        <item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator</item>

        <!-- Copy our color theme attributes to the framework -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">?attr/colorControlActivated</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">?attr/colorControlHighlight</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" parent="Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">

        <!-- Action Bar styling attributes -->
        <item name="actionBarSize">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
        <item name="actionBarDivider">?android:attr/actionBarDivider</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">?android:attr/actionButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">?android:attr/actionMenuTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">?android:attr/actionModeBackground</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">?android:attr/actionModeCloseDrawable</item>
        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">?android:attr/actionModeShareDrawable</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">?android:attr/actionOverflowButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">?android:attr/homeAsUpIndicator</item>

        <!-- For PopupMenu -->
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu</item>

        <!-- General view attributes -->
        <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
        <item name="dividerHorizontal">?android:attr/dividerHorizontal</item>
        <item name="dividerVertical">?android:attr/dividerVertical</item>
        <item name="editTextBackground">?android:attr/editTextBackground</item>
        <item name="editTextColor">?android:attr/editTextColor</item>
        <item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator</item>

        <!-- Copy our color theme attributes to the framework -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">?attr/colorControlActivated</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">?attr/colorControlHighlight</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- Action Bar styling attributes -->
        <item name="actionBarSize">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
        <item name="actionBarDivider">?android:attr/actionBarDivider</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">?android:attr/actionButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">?android:attr/actionMenuTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">?android:attr/actionModeBackground</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">?android:attr/actionModeCloseDrawable</item>
        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">?android:attr/actionModeShareDrawable</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">?android:attr/actionOverflowButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">?android:attr/homeAsUpIndicator</item>

        <!-- For PopupMenu -->
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu</item>

        <!-- General view attributes -->
        <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
        <item name="dividerHorizontal">?android:attr/dividerHorizontal</item>
        <item name="dividerVertical">?android:attr/dividerVertical</item>
        <item name="editTextBackground">?android:attr/editTextBackground</item>
        <item name="editTextColor">?android:attr/editTextColor</item>
        <item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator</item>

        <!-- Copy our color theme attributes to the framework -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">?attr/colorControlActivated</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">?attr/colorControlHighlight</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" parent="Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

        <!-- Action Bar styling attributes -->
        <item name="actionBarSize">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
        <item name="actionBarDivider">?android:attr/actionBarDivider</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">?android:attr/actionButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">?android:attr/actionMenuTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">?android:attr/actionModeBackground</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">?android:attr/actionModeCloseDrawable</item>
        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">?android:attr/actionModeShareDrawable</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">?android:attr/actionOverflowButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">?android:attr/homeAsUpIndicator</item>

        <!-- For PopupMenu -->
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu</item>

        <!-- General view attributes -->
        <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
        <item name="dividerHorizontal">?android:attr/dividerHorizontal</item>
        <item name="dividerVertical">?android:attr/dividerVertical</item>
        <item name="editTextBackground">?android:attr/editTextBackground</item>
        <item name="editTextColor">?android:attr/editTextColor</item>
        <item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator</item>

        <!-- Copy our color theme attributes to the framework -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">?attr/colorControlActivated</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">?attr/colorControlHighlight</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText" parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView" parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode" parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActivityChooserView" parent="">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="android:divider">?attr/dividerVertical</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">6dip</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView" parent="android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView" />

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner" parent="android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner" />

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView" parent="android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView" />

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">-4dip</item>
        <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow" parent="android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown" parent="android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown" />

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu" parent="android:Widget.Material.ListView" />

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">-4dip</item>
        <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" parent="android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal"></style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner" parent="android:Widget.Material.Spinner" />

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Material.Spinner">
        <item name="spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
        <item name="disableChildrenWhenDisabled">true</item>
        <item name="popupPromptView">@layout/abc_simple_dropdown_hint</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation" parent="android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation"></style>

    <style name="Platform.AppCompat" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Platform.AppCompat.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Platform.AppCompat.Light" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Platform.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I am stuck now.It was working well in eclipse.What should I for resolve this problem ?

Comment: what is your project directory structure? how does your build.gradle look like?

Comment: You have to put in the dependency for compat library v7 in your build.gradle of your app module.

Comment: I have multiple gradle files : http://prntscr.com/6316mf Is this correct ?

Comment: How did you migrate your project?  Did you import the eclipse project directly or did you attempt to export to gradle build in Eclipse then import into Android Studio?

Comment: I imported eclipse project directly.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?  Syncing with gradle?

Comment: Yes,I tried it but same result.

Comment: I agree with other commentors, you need to post your directory structure.

Comment: How can I post it ? Do you want gradle files ? Can you explain more ?

Comment: Can you post another screen shot of your directory structure?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/631j38 is this enough ?

Comment: Do you have a build.gradle in each of those directories?  Or are they all in the base directory.

Comment: This is project gradle file : http://prntscr.com/631lgi I don't know anything about gradle files. Is my structure is wrong ?

Comment: I think you need to have the build.gradle file located in each of the individual directories, not the root directory.

Comment: Can you explain step by step in answer ?

Comment: I would go back to Eclipse and export it to a gradle project.  If you don't have that option then update Eclipse.  Then you can import it to Android Studio and everything should be in place.